# Как отправить сообщение в ОПРЕДЕЛЁННУЮ ТЕМУ в групповом чате Telegram с помощю библиотеки aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram-2.x

Как отправить сообщение в определённую тему в групповом чате? Мне выдаёт ошибку при попытке отправить сообщение по ID чата. Мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Topic_closed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/Документы/Python/TelegramPoputkaBot/handlers/other.py", line 31, in get_id
    mess = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 346, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "/home/devilnoone/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Topic_closed
```

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно это будет полезно.
Когда ты создаешь тему, ты отправляешь сообщение "Тема "тема А" создана". И когда ты пишешь в эту тему, то ты постоянно отвечаешь на сообщение "Тема "тема А" создана".
То есть если ты отключишь опцию "Темы" в своем чате, то ты увидишь что когда ты писал в тему "тема А" то ты отвечал на сообщение о создании темы.
То есть чтобы бот писал в ту тему в которую ты хочешь, то просто получи Айди сообщения о создании темы. Либо отправь сообщение любое в эту тему и напечатай в откладке (консоли) `message.message_thread.id`.
Затем ты хочешь чтобы бот писал в эту тему, значит команда выглядит так:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id = -10012345689, text = "что-нибудь", reply_to_message_id = айдишник сообщения о создании темы (integer))
```

Надеюсь помогло. Просто знай что когда ты пишешь в тему, то ты отвечаешь на сообщение о создании темы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параметр `message_thread_id`

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "some text", message_thread_id=message.message_thread_id)
```

Comment: Возможно в библиотеке aiogram это работает иначе, но данный параметр 100% там будет
Я использую PyTelegramBotApi v3.14