# У сообщения в тг нет параметра message_thread_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь написать простого бота, который бы постил сообщения в тему группы ТГ. Все кого читал пишут, что нужно использовать параметр `message_thread_id`, но у меня проблема.
Если посмотреть в свойства сообщения там вообще нет такого параметра, а команда

```
await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id,text= "some text",message_thread_id=3)
```

пишет что

> message_thread_id - Unexpected argument

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки, пожалуйста, и добавьте метку [python].

Comment: TypeError: Bot.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message_thread_id'

Comment: Есть ощущение, что я что то не так пишу, потому что обновив aiogrm с 3.0.0.8b до 3.1.1 всё получилось как задумано. Но проблема в том, что там сильно отличается синтаксис, было бы приятнее запустить на текущей версии

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476368/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%81%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%A3%D0%AE-%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%A3-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-telegram-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8E-%D0%B1